# Replacing string "true" and "false" from union type to booleans

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've got one union type that is constructed from object keys, which may contain string, number, and boolean keys.

Example:

```
type Example = "true" | "semi" | "false";
```

What I want to achieve is to get a new type, which replaces strings `true` or `false` with actual boolean values.

```
type Example = true | "semi" | false;
```

**Converting directly to boolean won't work since there might be cases where I don't have either `true` or `false`**

This is what I've tried

```
type ReplaceTrue<T> = Extract<T, "true"> extends never ? T : Exclude<T, "true"> | true;
type ReplaceFalse<T> = Extract<T, "false"> extends never ? T : Exclude<T, "false"> | false;

type PickMyType<T> = ReplaceBoolean<T, "true", true> | ReplaceBoolean<T, "false", false>
```

I've also tried combining `ReplaceTrue` and `ReplaceFalse` to a single type, but I think that this would lead to a more unreadable code.

However, I feel like these solutions are not elegant and I'm wondering if there is any other method of replacing them.

Comment: On mobile, but I’d expect `type ReplBool<T> = T extends "true" ? true : T extends "false" ? false : T` to work and be the most straightforward.

Comment: @jcalz I need to exclude the `"true"` and/or `"false"` and also keep the rest of the types from the union.

Comment: In the case that T is neither "true" or "false" then @jcalz approach 'falls through' to T. Doesn't that achieve what you need?

Comment: However, I struggled to actually provide an elegant implementation, since I get complaints... https://tsplay.dev/N7PG4m

Comment: @MariusFlorescu It seems you didn't try the suggested solution.  I've posted it as an answer for completeness, since it does exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable by a straightforward [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type ReplBool<T> = T extends "true" ? true : T extends "false" ? false : T;

type Example = "true" | "semi" | "false";
type ReplacedExample = ReplBool<Example>;
// type ReplacedExample = boolean | "semi"
// note that boolean is an alias for true | false
```

You can do more complicated things involving mapped lookups or nested utility types, but the above definition is probably the tersest definition for something with just two cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYBsBCB7FCA8AVAfFAvFFlBAB7AQB2AJgM5QBEwATgK4QNQD8UL7UALiIlyVOowBmAQwS0O3KNNnQhWANwBYAFDbQkKAFFSUgLaJohJm3kAfRnJMBLTnYZK5DTVr3Q4iKQDGENRGpuYEsPDIaJihZggQOF4A9Mm84L5RgcFx4YQARjEQUpRQrg7O2qlQlCgUvAAWUsBQhejFpY70JVAyjlL0EijMvNZlijJyQA)

Answer (score 2):

Using a mapping type:

```
type T1 = "true" | "semi" | "false";

type Mapping = { true: true; false: false };
type T2 = Mapping[T1 & keyof Mapping] | Exclude<T1, keyof Mapping>;
// T2 = boolean | "semi"
```